# mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a following stored procedure to insert rows in the table panel_user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE panel_users()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE user_id BIGINT(20);
DECLARE panel_id BIGINT(20);
DECLARE wt DECIMAL(10,6);
DECLARE level DECIMAL(6,2);
DECLARE total INTEGER;
SET i=1;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total FROM smartmeter_usage.users_reporting;
WHILE i<=total DO
  SELECT u.userId INTO user_id, p.panelId INTO panel_id, ur.usage_percent INTO level, ipr.wt_base INTO wt
  FROM mondrainusage.user_d u 
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.imei_phone_reporting ipr ON u.imeiNumber = ipr.IMEI 
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.users_reporting ur ON ur.mobile_number = ipr.mobile_number
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.panel pn ON pn.panel_id = ur.panel_id
  INNER JOIN mondrainusage.panel p ON p.panelName = pn.panel_name
  WHERE u.userId = i;
  INSERT INTO mondrainusage.panel_user (panelId, userId, userWeight, usageLevel)  VALUES(panel_id, user_id, wt, level);
  SET i = i+1;
END WHILE
END
```

I am getting following error:

```
Undeclared variable: p
```

I am not getting what is wrong here in my query. Is there a way out of it?

**EDIT:**

k I got the solution for the above problem. here is the solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE panel_users()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE user_id BIGINT(20);
DECLARE panel_id BIGINT(20);
DECLARE wt DECIMAL(10,6);
DECLARE level DECIMAL(6,2);
DECLARE total INTEGER;
SET i=1;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total FROM smartmeter_usage.users_reporting;
WHILE i<=total DO
  SELECT u.userId, p.panelId, ur.usage_percent, ipr.wt_base INTO user_id,  panel_id,  level, wt
  FROM mondrainusage.user_d u 
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.imei_phone_reporting ipr ON u.imeiNumber = ipr.IMEI 
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.users_reporting ur ON ur.mobile_number = ipr.mobile_number
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.panel pn ON pn.panel_id = ur.panel_id
  INNER JOIN mondrainusage.panel p ON p.panelName = pn.panel_name
  WHERE u.userId = i;
  INSERT INTO mondrainusage.panel_user (panelId, userId, userWeight, usageLevel) VALUES(panel_id, user_id, wt, level);
  SET i = i+1;
 END WHILE
END
```

Bit now it is giving me syntax error near 'END' at line 21.

Why is this so?

**EDIT:**

Got the solution:

```
END WHILE;
```

Comment: @N.B.: I didn't got you?

Comment: @srahul07 He means you've never marked an answer to one of your questions as an answer.

Comment: it means you've asked 9 questions according to your profile, and you've not accepted a final answer on a single one.

Comment: can anyone please let me know what went wrong here in my procedure...

Comment: @srahul07 You should indeed post an *answer* to your own question, and accept it. That's the way StackOverflow works.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes I got solution and posted it in Edit only. I forgot to put semicolon. But since you have insisted it, posting it as a answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE panel_users()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE user_id BIGINT(20);
DECLARE panel_id BIGINT(20);
DECLARE wt DECIMAL(10,6);
DECLARE level DECIMAL(6,2);
DECLARE total INTEGER;
SET i=1;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total FROM smartmeter_usage.users_reporting;
WHILE i<=total DO
  SELECT u.userId, p.panelId, ur.usage_percent, ipr.wt_base INTO user_id,  panel_id,  level, wt
  FROM mondrainusage.user_d u 
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.imei_phone_reporting ipr ON u.imeiNumber = ipr.IMEI 
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.users_reporting ur ON ur.mobile_number = ipr.mobile_number
  INNER JOIN smartmeter_usage.panel pn ON pn.panel_id = ur.panel_id
  INNER JOIN mondrainusage.panel p ON p.panelName = pn.panel_name
  WHERE u.userId = i;
  INSERT INTO mondrainusage.panel_user (panelId, userId, userWeight, usageLevel) VALUES(panel_id, user_id, wt, level);
  SET i = i+1;
 END WHILE;
END
```